# Calculate the first day of a calendar week

Tags: c++, calendar, date

I need to calculate the date of the first day in a calendar week, e.g.

Week 1 in 2009 -> Mon, 29.12.2008 (!)
Week 44 in 2009 -> Mon, 26.10.2009

I have some ugly code for this, but I would prefer a nice C++ lib.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what about [boost::gregorian::date](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html#date_time.gregorian.date_class) with its [algorithms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html#date_time.gregorian.date_algorithms) ?

Comment: I'm thinking that the Boost's Date Time is the best solution!